# Enable action bar back button like hardware back button

Tags: android

I have many fragments in an activity. I move to some activity from one of the fragments. There are two cases. If I press hardware back button, I move back to the fragment from which current activity was called. But using action bar back button, previous activity is launched from onCreate state,like the very first fragment that I use when that activity is launched at first. Here is the code for action bar back button for second activity:
in onCreate: `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`
then I use:

```
 @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
```

How do I get the same function in action bar back button as in hardware bach button: onbackpressed??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call the method `onBackPressed();` of the Activity to give you the ability to back button just like the hardware back button.

if you are in fragment call `getActivity().onBackPressed()`

Answer (score 5):

In the switch statement, change

```
case android.R.id.home:
    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
    return true;
```

to

```
case android.R.id.home:
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
```

Comment: @Ryan    You saved my day . Thanks :)