# AppCompat Toolbar "back" button pressed not passing onCreate a savedInstanceState

Tags: android

When using the AppCompat toolbar with an AppCompatActivity, I've noticed that when pressing the back button on the toolbar, I'm not receiving a savedInstanceState in the onCreate method.

I have no problem saving and restoring state in Activity 1 + Fragment A while doing things to cause onSaveInstanceState to be fired (rotation, home button presses, etc.), but when I navigate to Activity 2, present the "back" button in the ToolBar, and tap that back button to navigate back to Activity 1 + Fragment A, savedInstanceState is null in both Activity 1 and Fragment A's onCreate.

I'm sure I'm just missing something (it's 4am local time here) and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable action bar back button like hardware back button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081862/enable-action-bar-back-button-like-hardware-back-button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flagging as duplicate of [Enable action bar back button like hardware back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081862/enable-action-bar-back-button-like-hardware-back-button?rq=1)

Question isn't identical but has same issue. Backbutton in appcompat toolbar causing `onCreate()` to be fired with null `Bundle savedInstanceState`.

Solution is to override back button behavior and call the activity's `onBackPressed()`.